# How can I restrict to delete parent record when child records exist using triggers?

Tags: trigger

I have created  created an account with 2 contacts.
if i try to delete account record it has to say child records are existing please 
remove child records first  .

---

```
trigger acccondel on Account (before delete) {
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();  
    Set<id> accIdSet = new Set<id>();  
    for(Account acc : Trigger.old)  
    {  
        accIdSet.add(acc.id);  
    }  

    Map<Id, Account> accts = new Map<Id, Account>([Select Id, (Select Id from contacts) from Account where id in :accIdSet]);

    for(Account acc : Trigger.old)
    {
        if(accts.get(acc.id).contacts.size()>0)
        {
            acc.adderror('You can not delete a account when it is having associated child contacts ');
            }
        }                                       

}
```

Comment: can you post your code whatever you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this trigger with a lot less CPU time and memory usage, with the following trigger:

```
trigger PreventDeleteWithContacts on Account (before delete) {
    // Shallow copy map
    Map<Id, Account> oldCopy = Trigger.oldMap.clone();
    // Keep only accounts that have at least one contact
    oldCopy.keySet().retainAll(
        new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
            [SELECT AccountId Id 
             FROM Contact 
             WHERE AccountId = :Trigger.old 
             GROUP BY AccountId]).keySet());
    // Show error
    for(Account record: oldCopy.values()) {
        record.addError('You cannot delete an account with contacts.');
    }
}
```

We use the filter by list reference so we don't need a temporary variable for the filter, and use the Id-AggregateResult map so we don't need to iterate over the results or have a second temporary variable. The oldCopy map will contain only accounts that have at least one contact.

Comment: Your approach is great, i think last for loop is not needed, just a size check and throwing an exception will serve the purpose

Comment: @SantanuBoral That would disable the "allOrNone" partial update behavior, which is generally undesirable. The client should be able to choose if a partial update is acceptable.

Comment: Not getting how this could disable partial update behavior. I'm talking about throwing error based on oldcopy.size()>0

Comment: @SantanuBoral Say I try to delete 10 accounts, and 5 of them can't be deleted. If I throw an exception, then that exception is applied to all 10 accounts. Otherwise, if I use addError per record, then a partial success would result in 5 accounts with errors and 5 successfully deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You approach will be like this:

1. Create a `before delete` trigger on Account object
2. retrieve `trigger.oldMap.ketSet()` to get the AccountIds to be deleted.
3. Write an aggregate query to check if contact id exists

*SOQL*

```
SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) contactCount
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId IN: listOfAccounts
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING Count(Id) > 0
```

4. Loop through `AggregateResult` and throw the error message.